# Filter object recursively with removing tailing matched nodes

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have common problem with filtering all matching nodes with parents in object. Quite easy if we get match in leafs. Problem is in nested not matching branches. Currently when I face some node with any children's it is possible that one of them will match, so I need to add this parent as potential match.
When I go couple levels down and not get match, visited "possible" nodes left and I need to go again through whole tree again to find those (couple times).
I have ugly solution: First get tree level and repeat filtering in for-loop to not add those children-less nodes. This is bad because is inaccurate.

I want to call filtering once to get result.

In below code, after 5 iterations of "cleaning", it finally returns proper result.

Expected result:

```
[{
    "content": { "name": "match" },
    "children": []
}]
```

Script:

```js
const items = [{
    content: { name: "match" },
    children: [{
        content: { name: "miss 1" },
        children: [{
            content: { name: "miss 2" },
            children: [{
                content: { name: "node 1" },
                children: []
            }, {
                content: { name: "node 2" },
                children: [{
                content: { name: "node 2" },
                children: []
                }, {
                    content: { name: "node 22" },
                    children: [{
                    content: { name: "node 23" },
                    children: []
                    }]
                }, {
                    content: { name: "node 23" },
                    children: []
                }]
            }, {
                content: { name: "node 3" },
                children: []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}, {
    content: { name: "Root 2" },
    children: []
}];

searchText = "match";

function filterItems(items, searchText) {
    var filtredItems = [];

    items.forEach(
        item => {
            if (item.children.length > 0 || item.content.name.includes(searchText)) {
                item.children = filterItems(item.children, searchText);
                filtredItems.push(item);
            }
        } 
    )
    return filtredItems;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(filterItems(items, searchText), null, 2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(filterItems(items, searchText), null, 2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(filterItems(items, searchText), null, 2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(filterItems(items, searchText), null, 2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(filterItems(items, searchText), null, 2)); // finally get result here
```

ok, so this suppose to be search feature in tree view. Searching for some name I need to get matching node with all parents way up to the root and without any other branches, also without children's once any is not match. Example use cases:

```
tree = 
[aa
    bb
    cc
        dd
            ff
            gg
        hh
        cc      
]       

search for:
aa =>
[aa]

dd =>
[aa
    cc
        dd
]

cc =>
[aa
    cc
        cc
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is that you want to filter the nodes, I would first flatten the tree recursively, and then filter the resulting array:

```
function recFlatten (list, item) {
  list.push(item)
  if (item.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
    for (var i in item.children) {
      if (item.children.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        recFlatten(list, item.children[i])
      }
    }
  }
  return list
}
var flatList = recFlatten([], items[0]})
var results = flatList.filter(item => ...)
```

Comment: hmm, this array is bound to view so I can't modify hierarchy. By flattening you can check if there are an empty nodes right? So, do filtering, than do flattening and check if there are still empty nodes, if yes do filter again. This could improve accuracy but still more than one filtering needs to be executed

Comment: I may not be exactly understanding your question here. The function I wrote above will not modify the existing hierarchy, it will return a new array with the flattened results, that you can then filter once to get your results.

Comment: could you please explain filtering idea here? I run your code (assuming typo(?) `recGetCat()` should be`recFlatten()`) and I get array of flatten objects. I can do filter now to search name of the e.g. root and I'll get the same object as before - containing children's which not match

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursice approach for the children and if some the name match or some children match, then create a new object with `content` property an the matching children.

```js
function getNodes(array, name) {
    return array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var temp = getNodes(a.children, name);
        return r.concat(
            a.content.name.includes(name) || temp.length ?
            Object.assign({}, a, { children: temp }) :
            []
        );
    }, []);
}

var items = [{ content: { name: "match" }, children: [{ content: { name: "miss 1" }, children: [{ content: { name: "miss 2" }, children: [{ content: { name: "node 1" }, children: [] }, { content: { name: "node 2" }, children: [{ content: { name: "node 2" }, children: [] }, { content: { name: "node 22" }, children: [{ content: { name: "node 23" }, children: [] }] }, { content: { name: "node 23" }, children: [] }] }, { content: { name: "node 3" }, children: [] }] }] }] }, { content: { name: "Root 2" }, children: [] }];

console.log(getNodes(items, 'match'));
console.log(getNodes(items, 'miss 1'));
console.log(getNodes(items, 'node 1'));
console.log(getNodes(items, 'node 2'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: yes, it work as it should:) just I need to avoid manually creation of object. In fact those nodes are abstractions for other objects and hold them references. Only properties `name` and `children` are used in this filter feature, so I used only them to simplify problem with simpler model

Comment: @Monika, please see edit, now with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), which generates a new object with all properties from the original one without mutating the source.